# connect to dynamic server

Tags: vb6, ip, connect

I want to develop and application in vb6+(vb6 upwards) in winxp+ (windows xp upwards). The client has to connect or reconnect to a server application.

How do i connect to the server whose ip is dynamic?

Comment: There is no "upwards" from vb6. vb6 is the final version of that language. After vb6 came .Net, and VB.Net is a **new** language, not the next vb6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having the server tell your client about its IP, for example by using one of many dynamic DNS services to give it a domain name, or by using a server of your own with a known address to store the IP address of your dynamic server.

Comment: Expanding on the first part of this answer, try a service such as dyndns.com's dynamic DNS offering

Comment: will an application built to rely on a website service be reliable?

Comment: @Oghenero: If the "website service" is reliable, yes. If you don't want to rely on an external provider, set up your own static server to store the IP address on.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen. can you give me sample code or tutorial that tackles this issue?

Comment: @Oghenero: You're a programmer, you're supposed to be able to write code by yourself.

Comment: please give me some of these dynamic DNS services

Answer (score 1):

With the help of broadcasting or preferrably multicasting the server's ip address in form of UDP datagram packets over network and join the client with the multicast group; client could know the address of the server. And thus could connect